# How to add column to a table based on another columns value in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in the database which looks like this:

```
#table_tstamp
id, tstamp
1, 12.11
2, 14.0
3, 18.22
4, 24.34
```

I want to another column to this table, and iterate over the values in tstamp such that new value= {tstamp(i)*2+5} such that the updated table would look like

```
#table_tstamp
id, tstamp, ts_new
1, 12.11, 29.22
2, 14.0 , 33.0
3, 18.22, 41.44
4, 24.34, 53.68
```

I tried this code but didn't work for me(though the column fetch_ts got created, but has NULL values):

```
ALTER TABLE table_tstamp
ADD fetch_ts float; 

insert into table_tstamp 
   SELECT 2*t2.tstamp+5 FROM table_tstamp t2;

#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use UPDATE instead of INSERT

```
ALTER TABLE table_tstamp ADD fetch_ts float; 

UPDATE table_tstamp SET fetch_ts = 2*tstamp+5
```